# Use solidity contracts public property and method in web3js.Error: Invalid bytes string given: 0x

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to use contract's property and method by web3js:

versions:

```
  "ganache-cli": "^6.3.0",
  "mocha": "^6.0.1",
  "solc": "^0.5.0",
  "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.47"
```

Imooc.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Course {
    string public name;

    constructor(string memory _name) public {
        name = _name;
    }

    function getName() public view returns (string memory) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

This contract work well in remix.

In my project, i use mocha to test contract.

course.spec.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const assert = require('assert');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3('ws://localhost:8545');

const Imooc = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/compiled/Imooc.json'));

let accounts;

describe('test', () => {
  before(async () => {
    accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    myCourse = await new web3.eth.Contract(Imooc.Course.abi, accounts[0]);

    myCourse.deploy({
      data: Imooc.Course.evm.bytecode.object,
      arguments: ['vue course']
    }).send({
      from: accounts[0]
    });
  });

  it('test 1', async () => {
    // const name = await myCourse.methods.name().call({from: accounts[0]});  // error too
    const name = await myCourse.methods.getName().call(from: accounts[0]);
    console.log(name);
  })
});
```

error:

```
Error: Invalid bytes string given: 0x
      at AbiCoder.decodeParameters (node_modules\web3-eth-abi\dist\web3-eth-abi.cjs.js:64:15)
      at CallContractMethod.afterExecution (node_modules\web3-eth-contract\dist\web3-eth-contract.cjs.js:740:32)
      at CallContractMethod._callee$ (node_modules\web3-core-method\dist\web3-core-method.cjs.js:354:35)
      at tryCatch (node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:62:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:288:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules\@babel\runtime\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:114:21)
      at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
      at _next (node_modules\@babel\runtime\helpers\asyncToGenerator.js:25:9)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I don't know why such easy code can't work, i look web3js docs and issue, but can not solve.And I change ganache to 6.2.3, web3js to beta.37, it is the same error.

I not use truffle. My project is react app, Course.sol is compiled to Imooc.json by solc.

ganache-cli:

```
ganache-cli
Ganache CLI v6.3.0 (ganache-core: 2.4.0)

Available Accounts
==================
(0) 0x089e993f812048134a7d75e59d2fcb7304da1d93 (~100 ETH)
(1) 0x8c7e0a256394e58e87aa1c49106e62db451877a8 (~100 ETH)
(2) 0x06e4263fbd0f03677f4a4c3973d0b128ce2b3623 (~100 ETH)
(3) 0x5fcd51e53682513b09e224c070063bc307fecb81 (~100 ETH)
(4) 0x482546b315bb1c2108cd49f24a6f1263ab51ae60 (~100 ETH)
(5) 0x8c1bf484291756dfaf48b4a5dedbfc1d0c606849 (~100 ETH)
(6) 0xda9764c54411fe0ec19f352227267c443fca290e (~100 ETH)
(7) 0x5f342a94691efc139d595614eea1d291b717cf0b (~100 ETH)
(8) 0x2accd39614f4956b4a079602328bddc3992fc980 (~100 ETH)
(9) 0x85afa7599881fe7804223b582bb13721a9ff902e (~100 ETH)

Private Keys
==================
(0) 0xd2f7a6deab5079600831a612287bf410feffb8fedda357f74668f3db806a4fc1
(1) 0x1bfb04383ae1ea3f1d0c3e307e384638d978b49e259f17aafe22afb3bbe3f535
(2) 0xdd773f1b63b60ab12a5ca3c235809955fed7c4206be864d513690e360425dfc1
(3) 0x6e9e339b5fed6c38daea7fece2e270f47ac6369d815ed54598d5d9ab4e3ae16a
(4) 0x5313296265239f11ef11f2412d5fd3eba679886620108b5fd5bf534db8d964cc
(5) 0x1d167ede831333af75873b970d99b03f8e90937fd5af0ccf937d74fa274ccd30
(6) 0xb216129764e1dd7a7476ad1380e52cfcf0c8ec7a62458a34fc3443f82dab9177
(7) 0x9b8ce17c00fb2ab851f3a3fd02aaf478e86f4d42381d809a5c3a9fbba8388ee4
(8) 0x2ff6a61071c0f989727200fb971406e17b1546729341fcc4fef7c557286b820b
(9) 0x90b99b181f131f352b696e4fcd8dfd151137ec2ab5535b31ea830ef61dad2490

HD Wallet
==================
Mnemonic:      retreat grant snap merge mansion cricket charge rebuild curious mix mobile hero
Base HD Path:  m/44'/60'/0'/0/{account_index}

Gas Price
==================
20000000000

Gas Limit
==================
6721975

Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545
```

Comment: What is your `ganache-cli` command line, and (assuming that you're using Truffle) what is your `truffle` command line?

Comment: @goodvibration updated.

Comment: Deal with it. [See this issue](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2445)

Answer (score 1):

```
const name = await myCourse.methods.name().call({from: accounts[0]});
```

Why are you using methods in this line of code. Try replacing with:

```
const name = await myCourse.name.call({from: accounts[0]});
```

Comment: Is not property `name` compile to a function? `myCourse.name` is undefined. And why ```myCourse.methods.getName().call(from: accounts[0]);``` the same error?

Comment: `Why are you using methods in this line of code` - because that's the syntax in web3.js v1.0. Your suggestion will work for web3.js v0.x, and in any case, the error described in the question does not imply that `.methods` is the problem. In fact, it implies that `.methods` is **NOT** the problem. If it was, then the error would be `undefined does not have a property 'getName'` (or something similar to that).

Comment: doesn't work. TypeError: _this.airdrop.getAddressDnaIds is not a function